Why is using the "distance.cosine" function from SciPy faster than directly executing its Python code?
I am executing the below two code snippets to calculate the cosine similarity of two vectors where the vectors are the same for both executions and the code for the second one is mainly the code SciPy is running (see scipy cosine implementation).
The thing is that when calling SciPy it is running slightly faster (~0.55ms vs ~0.69ms) and I don't understand why, as my implementation is like the one from SciPy removing some checks, which if something I would expect to make it faster.
Why is SciPy's function faster?

import time
import math

import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import distance

SIZE = 6400000
EXECUTIONS = 10000

path = "" # From https://github.com/joseprupi/cosine-similarity-comparison/blob/master/tools/vectors.csv
file_data = np.genfromtxt(path, delimiter=',')
A,B = np.moveaxis(file_data, 1, 0).astype('f')

accum = 0

start_time = time.time()
for _ in range(EXECUTIONS):    
    cos_sim = distance.cosine(A,B)

print(" %s ms" % (((time.time() - start_time) * 1000)/EXECUTIONS))
cos_sim_scipy = cos_sim

def cosine(u, v, w=None):
    
    uv = np.dot(u, v)
    uu = np.dot(u, u)
    vv = np.dot(v, v)
    dist = 1.0 - uv / math.sqrt(uu * vv)
    # Clip the result to avoid rounding error
    return np.clip(dist, 0.0, 2.0)

accum = 0

start_time = time.time()
for _ in range(EXECUTIONS):
    cos_sim = cosine(A,B)

print(" %s ms" % (((time.time() - start_time) * 1000)/EXECUTIONS))
cos_sim_manual = cos_sim

print(np.isclose(cos_sim_scipy, cos_sim_manual))

EDIT:
The code to generate A and B is below and the exact files I am using can be found at:
https://github.com/joseprupi/cosine-similarity-comparison/blob/master/tools/vectors.csv
def generate_random_vector(size):
    """
    Generate 2 random vectors with the provided size
    and save them in a text file
    """
    A = np.random.normal(loc=1.5, size=(size,))
    B = np.random.normal(loc=-1.5, scale=2.0, size=(size,))
    vectors = np.stack([A, B], axis=1)
    np.savetxt('vectors.csv', vectors, fmt='%f,%f')

generate_random_vector(640000)

Setup:

AMD Ryzen 9 3900X 12-Core Processor
64GB RAM
Debian 12
Python 3.11.2
scipy 1.13.0
numpy 1.26.4


Not reproducible. I consistently find scipy's version to be slower (at least 4.5x) than your slimmed-down version, which makes sense.

../tools/vectors.csv is not provided. Please update the code so not to use it (eg. use random number generators) or provide it. Also note that performance if very dependent of the version of the packages. Developers continuously improve performance and add new features. Last but not least, it is also dependent of your CPU reference which is not provided. For example np.dot can use multiple threads based on the size of the arrays. Creating threads can be slow depending on the number of core on your CPU. Much slower than the actual computation in some cases.

Are you sure that your SciPy is recent enough to be comparable? There have been multiple bigger changes to this function in the end of 2023 and a smaller change in March. See the blame.

@JérômeRichard Their generate_random_vector function creates that vectors.csv file.

@JérômeRichard You make a good point. Did OP copy the code from github but has a different version running on their machine such that they are not comparable?

@jared Ok, vectors.csv is indeed generated, so then ../tools/vectors.csv is certainly a miss-written path. Still, IDK if they are supposed to be comparable indeed. I also cannot reproduce the OP issue on my machine : the Scipy code is slower (5 ms vs 1.1 ms).

Sorry all, I have updated the code and added a link to the exact files I am using.

This is better. However, I still get 4.85 ms and 1.09 ms with the last version of the code and the new csv file on my machine (with an Intel i5-9600KF CPU, Python 3.8.1, Scipy 1.10.1 and Numpy 1.24.4 on Windows).

@JérômeRichard On numpy==1.26.4/scipy==1.13.0 on AMD 5700x/Ubuntu 20.04/Python 3.11 I get 0.458ms (scipy) vs 0.676ms (manual)

It seems, scipy does at the beginning of correlation() function this which practically means:
u = np.asarray(u, dtype=None, order="c")
v = np.asarray(v, dtype=None, order="c")

This ensures that the arrays are C_CONTIGUOUS (you can check this by printing u.flags and/or v.flags)
I presume numpy uses different implementations of np.dot for contiguos/non-contiguos arrays.

If you change your function to:
def cosine(u, v, w=None):
    u = np.asarray(u, dtype=None, order="c")  # <-- Ensure C_CONTIGUOUS True
    v = np.asarray(v, dtype=None, order="c")  # <-- detto.

    uv = np.dot(u, v)
    uu = np.dot(u, u)
    vv = np.dot(v, v)
    dist = 1.0 - uv / math.sqrt(uu * vv)
    # Clip the result to avoid rounding error
    return np.clip(dist, 0.0, 2.0)

I get the same results 0.45ms vs 0.45ms on my AMD 5700x.

This is strange : adding the two line make the code slower on my machine (fully reproducible 5 times). It is now 4.9 ms and 2.25 ms. So the Numpy version is twice slower with this fix.

I wonder if this is due to the CPU (or possibly the OS) : desktop AMD CPUs has multiple NUMA node while desktop Intel ones has not (UMA). This often has a strong impact on memory accesses and more generally when designing algorithms. OpenBLAS which is the default implementation is AFAIK not very NUMA aware. I think further investigation is needed if the OP plan to use its code on other (non-AMD) machines.

@JérômeRichard Yes, that's strange - you should see the same times. But I see your comment, you're using different versions (Python 3.8.1, Scipy 1.10.1 and Numpy 1.24.4... also Windows). Might be the issue? The implementation seems different on this version: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/c1ed5ece8ffbf05356a22a8106affcd11bd3aee0/scipy/spatial/distance.py#L610

I would point out that if you're looking for the fastest implementation, SimSIMD is faster than either SciPy or your manual implementation.
Example of how to use this:
import simsimd


def cosine(u, v, w=None):
    # Note: simsimd requires contiguous input
    u = np.asarray(u, dtype=None, order="c")
    v = np.asarray(v, dtype=None, order="c")
    return simsimd.cosine(u, v)

On my system, this is 13% faster. (1.60 ms vs 1.40 ms)

On my machine, your code using simsimd is slower than the Numpy version: 1.88 ms (vs 4.85 ms and 1.09 ms for respectively the Scipy and Numpy versions). It might be because of the same issue happening on the Andrej question.

@JérômeRichard Could also be that I'm running this in a VM with no access to SIMD intrinsics.
